# How to compare elements of File[] with name of each element in a list of objects

Tags: java

I need to know which files of a directory are not in my list. The code is as following and the problem is that I do not know how to compare them.

*Comparison is based on files names only.

```
File dir = new File(directory);
File[] files = dir.listFiles(); 

List<Records> myFiles; 
for(int i=0;i<myFiles.size();i++){
            System.err.println(myFiles.get(i).getDetails().getName());
}
```

As you can see I have a a list with File[] type that has a list of all files in the directory.
Also a list of type List that has all record objects.

Comment: What do you mean by "comparing" them? Are you trying to combine the lists in sorted order?

Comment: What attribute of a `File` do you intend to compare? Its contents? Just the physical location and the name?

Comment: @mystarrocks just names

Comment: @mc10 compare the name of the files to know which files are in the list that I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing different you need to do other than to lookup every file name from the `files` array in the `myFiles` list.

What did you try and what problems were you facing? Here's a quick implementation to get you started anyway.

```
/**
 * Returns a set of files in the {@code filesInDir} that are not included in the {@code myFiles} list.
 * 
 * <p>
 * Does a case insensitive comparison of file names to confirm presence.
 * 
 * @param filesInDir the files in a given directory
 * @param myFiles my list of files
 * @return files in the {@code filesInDir} that are not included in the {@code myFiles} list
 */
Set<File> filesNotIncludedInMyList(File[] filesInDir, List<Record> myFiles) {
    Set<File> filesNotInMyList = new HashSet<>();
    for (File fileInDirectory : filesInDir) {
        boolean fileInDirectoryIncludedInMyList = false;
        for (Record myFile : myFiles) {
            if (fileInDirectory.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(myFile.getDetails().getName())) {
                fileInDirectoryIncludedInMyList = true;
            }
        }
        if (! fileInDirectoryIncludedInMyList) {
            filesNotInMyList.add(fileInDirectory);
        }
    }

    return filesNotInMyList;
}
```

Here's a bit more readable version w/o the nested `for` loop. Of course this does a case-insensitive search (by lower casing all the file names), but you can do a case sensitive one if you wanted.

```
/**
 * Returns files in the {@code filesInDir} that are not included in the {@code myFiles} list.
 * 
 * <p>
 * Does a case insensitive comparison of file names to confirm presence.
 * 
 * @param filesInDir the files in a given directory
 * @param myFiles my list of files
 * @return files in the {@code filesInDir} that are not included in the {@code myFiles} list
 */
Set<File> filesNotIncludedInMyList(File[] filesInDir, List<Record> myFiles) {
    Set<File> filesNotInMyList = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> myFileNames = recordFileNames(myFiles);
    for (File fileInDirectory : filesInDir) {
        if (! myFileNames.contains(fileInDirectory.getName().toLowerCase())) {
            filesNotInMyList.add(fileInDirectory);
        }
    }

    return filesNotInMyList;
}

/**
 * Creates a set containing the file names of all the records in the given list of records.
 * 
 * @param myFiles my list of files
 * @return a set containing the file names of all the records in the given list of records
 */
Set<String> recordFileNames(List<Record> myFiles) {
    Set<String> recordFileNames = new HashSet<>();
    for (Record file : myFiles) {
        recordFileNames.add(file.getDetails().getName().toLowerCase());
    }
    return recordFileNames;
}
```

Comment: I did something similar to yours but I was wondering if there is any better way rather than a nested for loop

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the code the `List` `myFiles` isn't initialized yet ,, so you have to initialize this list first and then you can do all what u want...